# Maven Installation in linux fails with "The following packages have unmet dependencies" error

Tags: maven, apt-get, ubuntu-14.10

I am new to Linux I was trying to install Maven with

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

I hit upon this error

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/ utopic-updates/main openjdk-7-jre-headless amd64 7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1 [39.7 MB]
Fetched 1,031 B in 0s (7,897 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.excellmedia.net/archive/pool/main/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u75-2.5.4-1~utopic1_amd64.deb  Size mismatch

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

On googling i found out that I had to do

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and followed that

Now after doing above clean I tried installing again with

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

but now i am getting the following different error :-(

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 maven : Depends: libaether-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libplexus-containers1.5-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libsisu-ioc-java but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libwagon2-java (>= 2.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

I tired

```
sudo apt-get update
```

but it dint work I am currently using "Ubuntu 14.10".
Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will cause apt to scan and fix missing dependencies and fix them from the repositories configured for your system. Try installing maven again after this.

Comment: what can be side effects of using -f switch?